# Problem in training tensorflow model for multilabel comment classification

Tags: tensorflow, keras, text, training-data, multilabel-classification

Problem is in training phase

```
def mlp_model(layers, units, dropout_rate, input_shape, num_classes):

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, 20, input_length=maxlen ,input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Dropout(rate=dropout_rate, input_shape=input_shape))

for _ in range(layers-1):
    model.add(Dense(units=units, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(rate=dropout_rate))

model.add(GlobalMaxPool1D())
model.add(Dense(units=num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))
return model
```

---

```
    model = mlp_model(layers = 2, units = 50,dropout_rate = 0.2, input_shape = (100,), num_classes = 9)


model.compile(optimizer='adam' , loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC()])
callbacks = [
    ReduceLROnPlateau(),
    ModelCheckpoint(filepath='model-simple.h5', save_best_only=True)
]


history = model.fit(X_train.astype('float32'), y_train,
                    class_weight=class_weight,
                    epochs=25,
                    batch_size=32,
                    validation_split=0.2,
                    callbacks=callbacks)
```

_____________________________________________________________________-
And Finally i got this error :

> ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 0
> for '{{node binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Squeeze}} =
> SqueezeT=DT_FLOAT, squeeze_dims=[-1]' with input
> shapes: [?,0].

---

X_train shape : (99909, 100)
Y_train shape : (99909, 9)

Please help me , what is the problem ?!!

Answer (score 0):

What do the class weights look like? For me the following code works successfully:

```
max_words=1000
maxlen=15
def mlp_model(layers, units, dropout_rate, input_shape, num_classes):

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(max_words, 20, input_length=maxlen ,input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=dropout_rate, input_shape=input_shape))

for _ in range(layers-1):
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=units, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=dropout_rate))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool1D())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))
return model



X_train = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
y_train = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]

X_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_train)
y_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train)

print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)

model = mlp_model(layers = 2, units = 50,dropout_rate = 0.2, input_shape = 
(14,), num_classes = 9)


model.compile(optimizer='adam' , loss='binary_crossentropy')


history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                class_weight={0: 0.50,
                              1: 0.75,
                              2: 1,
                              3: 1.25,
                              4: 1.5,
                              5: 1.75,
                              6: 2,
                              7: 2.25,
                              8: 2.5},
                epochs=5,
                batch_size=32,
                callbacks=callbacks)
```

Comment: The weighting of the classes is to balance the data
And that the labels are hot, for example, a comment can have several labels, such as its label
[1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0]